# Current best-known Drake Equation values?

Tags: exoplanet, seti, drake-equation

[Frank Drake's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drake_equation) is used to estimate $N$ the number of civilizations we might be able to communicate with in our galaxy:

$$N = R_\star f_p n_e f_l f_i f_c L$$

where:

$R_\star$ is the average rate of star formation in the galaxy

$f_p$ is the fraction of stars with planets

$n_e$ is the average number of [goldilocks](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/astrobiology/goldilocks-worlds/) planets per planetary system

$f_l$ is the fraction of goldilocks planets that actually develop life

$f_i$ is the fraction of life bearing planets that develop intelligent life

$f_c$ is the fraction of civilizations that broadcast their existence into space

and $L$ is the length of time for which a civilization broadcasts their existence

### Question

Have the many exoplanets we've discovered in the last several decades improved our estimates of $f_p$, and $n_e$?  Are these values different than what was guessed about prior to the discovery of the first exoplanets?  What is our current best estimate for $R_\star$ for the Milky Way?

Comment: Have you consulted wikipedia on this? It seems there is a long discussion section about current values.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape Yeah, I'd like to see a little more detail about $f_p$ and $n_c$, particularly.  Also it seems like the wikipedia entry may be a bit dated.  A lot of the stuff is from 2011.

Comment: We collected a bunch of estimates in https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.02404 (see the supplementary files), showing their distributions, but for a deeper discussion see Vakoch, D. A., & Dowd, M. F. (Eds.). (2015). The Drake equation: estimating the prevalence of extraterrestrial life through the ages (Vol. 8). Cambridge University Press.

Answer (score 3):

> Have the many exoplanets we've discovered in the last several decades improved our estimates of , and ?

Absolutely! The quantity $f_p n_e$ is a quantity of much interest in investigations of extrasolar planets, which effectively equates to the fraction of stars that have a habitable planet in their star's habitable zone. Plenty of studies have examined this specifically for Earth-sized extrasolar planets and place the value of $f_p n_e$ between ~$\frac{1}{6}$ (i.e. one in six stars have an earth-sized planet in a relatively close orbit to the host star) and ~$\frac{2}{5}$ [[1]](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/kepler/news/17-percent-of-stars-have-earth-size-planets.html)[[2]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drake_equation#Fraction_of_those_stars_that_have_planets,_fp). A 2013 comprehensive study by Petigura is a great paper to get familiar with the specifics and assumptions of how the Kepler surveys are conducted and the quantities of interest calculated [[3]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.6806.pdf).

> What is our current best estimate for ⋆ for the Milky Way?

Unfortunately the answer is: it varies. Roughly, we think that the Milky Way puts out about 3 solar masses worth of new star every year [[4]](http://www.ism.ucalgary.ca/Star_Formation/How_Often.html#:%7E:text=This%20quantity%20is%20called%20the,necessarily%20go%20into%201%20star.). However, these don't have to be in one star. Since we think most stars are probably ~1 M$_\odot$, this works out to ~3 stars/year. However, some estimates go less, and some estimates (based on chemical decay of elements like aluminum) go as high as 7 stars/year [[5]](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/goddard/news/topstory/2006/milkyway_seven.html).

Comment: Most stars are more like 0.3 solar masses.

Comment: @ProfRob The justification for my statement can be found in the source I linked: "However, stars like our Sun (1 solar mass) are quite common and so we can approximate the star formation rate to be about 3 stars (like our Sun) per year in our Galaxy."  However, I appreciate there are different estimates on this number, and I believe the qualifier in my answer: "However, some estimates go less, and some estimates (based on chemical decay of elements like aluminum) go as high as 7 stars/year" with appropriate citations addresses the issue.